# How to plot button inside GridView cells in every row?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I'm implementing 12 by 31 days table using GridView. Where I can select on cell with a button click. I already implemented it somehow something wrong with the GridView it not plotted the last row which is the December row. I also used a hard coded html tag in cell to render a button. But it's also good if dynamically generated by control? And also if row it must equal to days of a month example: it will render 28 buttons on February.

Here's button click to load current data into GridView.

```
protected void ButtonFilter_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
                               DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();

                    dataTable.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[32]
                    {
                        new DataColumn("Month"),
                        new DataColumn("Day1"),
                        new DataColumn("Day2"),
                        new DataColumn("Day3"),
                        new DataColumn("Day4"),
                        new DataColumn("Day5"),
                        new DataColumn("Day6"),
                        new DataColumn("Day7"),
                        new DataColumn("Day8"),
                        new DataColumn("Day9"),
                        new DataColumn("Day10"),
                        new DataColumn("Day11"),
                        new DataColumn("Day12"),
                        new DataColumn("Day13"),
                        new DataColumn("Day14"),
                        new DataColumn("Day15"),
                        new DataColumn("Day16"),
                        new DataColumn("Day17"),
                        new DataColumn("Day18"),
                        new DataColumn("Day19"),
                        new DataColumn("Day20"),
                        new DataColumn("Day21"),
                        new DataColumn("Day22"),
                        new DataColumn("Day23"),
                        new DataColumn("Day24"),
                        new DataColumn("Day25"),
                        new DataColumn("Day26"),
                        new DataColumn("Day27"),
                        new DataColumn("Day28"),
                        new DataColumn("Day29"),
                        new DataColumn("Day30"),
                        new DataColumn("Day31")
                    });

                    DataRow dataRow;

                    var months = new string[] { "JAN", "FEB", "MAR", "APR", "MAY", "JUN", "JUL", "AUG", "SEP", "OCT", "NOV", "DEC" };

                    var button = new Button
                    {
                        ID = "ButtonCell",
                        Text = ""
                    };

                    for (int i = 0; i < comparePrices.Count; i++)
                    {
                        dataRow = dataTable.NewRow();

                        dataRow["Month"] = months[i];

                        for (int j = 0; j < comparePrices[i].Pricings.Count; j++)
                        {
                            // Load the here.
                            //dataRow[string.Format("Day{0}", j + 1)] = comparePrices[i].Pricings[j].Price;                            
                        }

                        dataTable.Rows.Add(dataRow);
                    }

                    ListOfComparePrice = comparePrices;

                    GridViewPricing.DataSource = dataTable;
                    GridViewPricing.DataBind();
                }
```

Here's the RowDataBound back-end code. The GridViewPricing.Rows.Count has 12. Columns has 32 count.

```
protected void GridViewPricing_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                foreach (GridViewRow row in GridViewPricing.Rows)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < GridViewPricing.Columns.Count; i++)
                    {
                        if (i != 0)
                        {
                            row.Cells[i].Text = string.Format("<div><input type='button' style='border: 0; display:block; padding:4px; width:100%; height:100%;' id={0}/></div>", "hi");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Also instead of hard coded html. I would like to use dynamic code in back-end to generate button.

```
 var button = new Button
                    {
                        ID = "ButtonCell",
                        Text = ""
                    };
```

Output:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GP7yi.png)

Comment: Looks like code inside `if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)` block is not being executed for DEC row. You need to debug and check what is the value of `e.Row.RowType` for DEC row...

Comment: What is the length of `comparePrices`? It looks like that `comparePrices` has length one less than the number of rows expected to be displayed in GridView.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have a nested loop. Inside the `GridViewPricing_RowDataBound` you have the following line

```
foreach (GridViewRow row in GridViewPricing.Rows)
```

But the RowDataBound event is already fired for every row, so each time you are looping the previous rows again. But the current row is only added to the GridView after the RowDataBound event. That is why you are missing the last row. It should be

```
protected void GridViewPricing_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < GridViewPricing.Columns.Count; i++)
        {
            if (i != 0)
            {
                row.Cells[i].Text = string.Format("<div><input type='button' style='border: 0; display:block; padding:4px; width:100%; height:100%;' id={0}/></div>", "hi");
            }
        }
    }
}
```